# How to check if a plugin using wp-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, wordpress

My server CPU usage get limited easily beacause there is 400,000 calls of /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

I tried to turn off Heartbeat, but the problem is still there.

I am trying to track which plugins using admin-ajax.php and turn them off properly.

1. My method is to search for keywords  `ajaxurl` and `admin-ajax.php` in all php file of plugins folder. Is that correct?

   - I found some plugin using that such as debug plugin, console debug plugin, jetpack, duplicator,...
   - There are too many plugins using admin-ajax.php. They keeps on calling admin-ajax.php .Please tell me how to fix this problem.
2. Will de-activate plugin completely turn off admin-ajax.php call? Or I need to delete completely that plugin?

Thank you very much.

Update 1:
I have just noticed that Debug Bar plugin maybe the problem. When I am at wp-admin, it keeps on showing notice related to jQuery error. In order to do that, maybe it use admin-ajax.php.

Anyway, I deleted the plugin and will check cpu usage in next few hour.

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/heartbeat-ajax-php-usage

Comment: i turned HeartBeat Off completely 10 days ago.

Comment: You can also look for actions starting with `wp_ajax_`

Comment: Deactivating the plugin will turn off the AJAX calls (answer to question no. 2.)

Comment: Inspect it in Chrome. Go to Network tab, and refresh your page, and check the XHR tab for any ajax call. [Check this link out](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)